# ¿Cómo combinar dos clases en python para utilizar sus métodos heredados?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Tengo esta clase llamada `Rango`:

```
class Rango(object):

    def __init__(self, inicio, fin):
        self.rango = range(inicio, fin)
        self.pos = -1
    
    def numero_RNC(self):
        self.pos += 1
        return self.rango[self.pos]
```

Tengo esta otra clase llamada `Productos` que hereda los métodos de la clase `Rango`:

```
class PRODUCTOS(Rango):
       
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.wind = root #ventana completa
        self.wind.title('Facturacion principal')
        self.wind.geometry("850x600")
```

Inicializo la instancia de la clase Rango dentro de la clase PRODUCTOS, pero al llamar a los métodos de la clase `Rango`, **me dice que la clase PRODUCTOS no tiene los atributos de la clase Rango**. Me podrían explicar como funciona eso, si no es mucha molestia. Saludos.

```
    instancia = Rango(inicio=2, fin=10)
    self.numero_RNC()
```

> EDITADO, intento pasarle el dato donde se modifica la variable inicio pero sin resultado, alguna idea? para luego llamarla desde dentro de la clase PRODUCTOS
> class Rango(object):

```
    def __init__(self, inicio, fin):
        self.rango = range(inicio, fin)
        self.pos = -1
    
    def numero_RNC(self):
        self.pos += 1
        return self.rango[self.pos]

        
inicio = 5
final = 10
primero = inicio
segundo = final



class PRODUCTOS(Rango):
    base_datos = "clientes_productos.db"
    resultado = 0.00 #valor x defecto self.resultado

 
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(inicio=primero, fin=segundo)
        self.wind = root #ventana completa
        self.wind.title('Facturacion principal')
        self.wind.geometry("850x600")
        self.numero_inicio = primero####
        self.numero_final=  segundo##### intento pasarle el dato
        
        self.numero_inicio = 14 #intento modificar el valor de inicio de RANGE
        self.numero_final = 20
        dato = self.numero_RNC()
        print(dato)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase hija debe inicializar explícitamente a la clase padre usando el formato general

```
super().__init__(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

donde `arg1`, `arg2`, etc. son los argumentos del constructor de la clase padre.

Si no lo haces, esos campos nunca serían inicializados, y cuando trates de ejecutar métodos de la clase padre, fallaran.

En tu caso quedaría así:

```
class Rango(object):

    def __init__(self, inicio, fin):
        self.rango = range(inicio, fin)
        self.pos = -1

    def numero_RNC(self):
        self.pos += 1
        return self.rango[self.pos]


class PRODUCTOS(Rango):

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(1, 10) # Pasando valores arbitrarios
        self.wind = root  # ventana completa
        self.wind.title('Facturacion principal')
        self.wind.geometry("850x600")
```

El otro error que tienes es

```
instancia = Rango(inicio=2, fin=10)
self.numero_RNC()
```

La variable `self` no está definida; no la puedes usar para nada. Lo correcto sería usar la `instancia` que recién creastes:

```
instancia = Rango(inicio=2, fin=10)
print(instancia.numero_RNC())    => 2
```

La variable `self` es una simple convención usada como primer argument para definir los **métodos de una clase**. El nombre puede ser cualquiera; sólo importa su ubicación.

Con la variable `self` tienes accesos a los atributos y métodos del propio objeto que los ejecuta.

#### Demo

En este ejemplo creamos una instancia de `Rango` y luego llamamos repetidamente a su método:

```
instancia = Rango(inicio=2, fin=10)

for _ in range(5):
    print(instancia.numero_RNC())
```

produce:

```
2
3
4
5
6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Saludos, por que? al crear la instancia no hereda el Rango.                               instancia = Rango(inicio=1, fin=10)
valor = instancia.numero_RNC() si hago print(valor) = 1,1,1,1,1,1  cada vez que la llame, en vez de 1,2,3,4,5,6... cada vez q la llame +1

Comment: @wally. Probablemente estas recreando la instancia en cada iteración. Agregué una demo a la respuesta para que veas el uso.

Comment: Saludos nuevamente, como puedo hacer para  asociarle una variable a, inicio y fin del  __init__(self, inicio, fin). Hize lo siguiente:                                                              def __init__(self, root,  contador_primero = 0, contador_segundo=5):
        super().__init__(inicio=contador_primero, fin=contador_segundo)
        self.primero = contador_primero
        self.segundo = contador_segundo:: pero no me deja asociarle una variable al contador dentro del init solo me deja asociarle numeros como se podria? la idea es poder manipular ese conteo a voluntad.

Comment: La sintaxis es incorrecta. Debería ser `self.primero=inicio`. `contador_primero` es el valor por default y **tiene que existir** antes que Python llegue a esa línea. Idem para las otras variables

Comment: Saludos otra vez, favor mira la pregunta nuevamente, le puse una edicion al final, para ver que opinas porque aun no logro capturar la variable INICIO, FINAL del RANGE porque sucede que cuando llamo al metodo self.numero_RNC desde la clase PRODUCTOS funciona bien el rango opteniendo 1+ en cada llamada. pero no logro acceder a las variables de rango desde PRODUCTOS

Answer (score 2):

Para que una clase herede de otra clase y compartir sus funciones debes de hacer lo siguiente:

Imaginate que tenemos una clase llamada
`class Perro(object)` y le damos los atributos:

```
class Perro(object):
    def __init__(self,nombre,color)
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.color=color
    def info(self):
        a="nombre:"+self.nombre+"\ncolor:"+self.color
        return a
```

Ahora creas la otra **clase** que heredara las funciones de la clase anterior.

```
class ladrar(Perro):
    def __init__(self,nombre,color):
        Perro.__init__(self,nombre=nombre,color=color)
    def ladrar_bajito(self):
        a="wiif"
        return a
    def ladrar_alto(self):
        a="wooooof"
        return a
```

Al poner `Perro.__init__()` ejecutamos la clase madre(`class Perro`) dentro de la clase hija(`class ladrar`) y haci podemos heredar las funciones dentro de otras clases.

```
a=ladrar("firulais","carmelita")
informacion=a.info()
print(informacion)
```

la funcion `info()` pertenece a la clase `Perro`.El codigo anterior te dara como resultado.

```
nombre:firulais
color:carmelita
```

tambien puedes llamar a las clases:

```
a.ladrar_bajito()
a.ladrar_alto()
```

si quieres guiarte por otro lado visita
la pagina de abajo:

> https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/algoritmos-python/capitulo-15/herencia

¿te fue util mi respuesta?

por favor valorala :) lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Gracias x haberte tomado tu tiempo en explicarme. nota para algun Admin: a esta pagina le falta la funcion LIKES para agradecer una respuesta que aporta a la respuesta definitiva, x q es injusto que varios colaboren y no reciban su pulgar arriba.

Comment: @wally si queres, podes votar positivo la respuesta (esos son los likes aqui y recompensan con reputacion al usuario que publicó), usa la flecha hacia arriba arriba a la izquierda. Te agradezco la intencion c: Por cierto, si queres proponer algo, podes hacerlo en meta. Te pasaria el link, pero estoy en celu.